# proof for posterior predictive of normal-gamma conjugacy

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

Giving the following equations
$$
\mu_n = \frac{\kappa_0 \mu_0 + n \overline{x}}{\kappa_0 + n}, \\
\kappa_n = \kappa_0 + n, \\
\alpha_n = \alpha_0 + n/2, \\
\beta_n = \beta_0 + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^2 + \frac{\kappa_0 n (\overline{x} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n)},
$$
where $\overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i }{n}$, i.e., the mean of data. Actually, the above equations are the parameters of the posterior of normal normal-gamma conjugacy (see Equation (85-89) in [this paper](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf) for details).

Here, I want to prove:
$$
\mu_{n+m} = \frac{\kappa_n \mu_n + m \overline{x}}{\kappa_n + m}, \\
\kappa_{n+m} = \kappa_n + m, \\
\alpha_{n+m} = \alpha_n + m/2, \\
\beta_{n+m} = \beta_n + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{n+m} (x_i - \overline{x})^2 + \frac{\kappa_n m (\overline{x} - \mu_n)^2}{2(\kappa_n + m)},
$$
where $\overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m} \quad x_i}{m}$, i.e., the mean of new observations. The above equations are appeared in Equation (101-104) of [this paper](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf), in which the $m$ is set as 1.

=============================================================

The following effort I have tried
$$
\kappa_{n+m} = \kappa_0 + n + m = \kappa_{n} + m \\
\alpha_{n+m} = \alpha_0 + \frac{n+m}{2} = \alpha_n + \frac{m}{2} \\
\mu_{n+m} = \frac{\kappa_0 \mu_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} x_i }{\kappa_0 + n+ m} = \frac{\kappa_0 \mu_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m} x_i }{\kappa_n + m} = \frac{(\kappa_0 + n)\frac{\kappa_0 \mu_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i }{\kappa_0 + n} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m} x_i }{\kappa_n + m} = \frac{\kappa_n \mu_n + m\overline{x}}{\kappa_n + m}
$$
where $\overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m} \quad x_i}{m}$. But I fail to prove the last equation:
$$
\beta_{n+m} = \beta_n + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{n+m} (x_i - \overline{x})^2 + \frac{\kappa_n m (\overline{x} - \mu_n)^2}{2(\kappa_n + m)}.
$$
So, could anybody give me some suggestions?

=============================================================
Update:

Thanks for Xi'an's help. The complete proof of the  posterior predictive of normal-gamma conjugacy is now available in [this note](https://j-zin.github.io/files/Conjugate_Bayesian_analysis_of_common_distributions.pdf) (see page 24: Proof of Normal Normal-Gamma Conjugacy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct and elegant way to show these identities is to exploit that the posterior distribution $\pi_{n+m}(\theta|\mathfrak D_{n+m})$ associated with the prior $\pi_0$ and the $n+m$ observations $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+m})$ is equal to the posterior distribution associated with the "prior" $\pi_n(\theta|\mathfrak D_{n})$ and the $m$ observations $(x_{n+1},\ldots,x_{n+m})$. When the prior is conjugate, e.g., Normal-Gamma, the intermediary posterior $\pi_n(\theta|\mathfrak D_{n})$ is also conjugate and the update of the hyperparameters is immediate.

A more pedestrian and dreary approach is to expand the expression of $\beta_{n+m}$. For the last update equation, let us introduce the notations $\overline{x}_{1:n+m}$, $\overline{x}_{1:n}$ and $\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}$ to distinguish between the three averages. Then
\begin{align}
\beta_{n+m} &= \beta_0 + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+m} (x_i - \overline{x}_{1:n+m})^2 + \frac{\kappa_0 (n+m) (\overline{x}_{1:n+m} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)}\\
&= \beta_0 + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x}_{1:n}+\overline{x}_{1:n}-\overline{x}_{1:n+m})^2\\
&\quad  + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{n+m} (x_i - \overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}+ \overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}- \overline{x}_{1:n+m})^2\\
&\quad + \frac{\kappa_0 (n\overline{x}_{1:n}+m\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} - (n+m)\mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}\\
&= \beta_0 + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \overline{x}_{1:n})^2+\frac{1}{2}n(\overline{x}_{1:n}-\overline{x}_{1:n+m})^2\\
&\quad  + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{n+m} (x_i - \overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)})^2+ \frac{1}{2}m(\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}- \overline{x}_{1:n+m})^2\\
&\quad + \frac{\kappa_0 (n\overline{x}_{1:n} - n\mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}+ \frac{\kappa_0 (m\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} - m\mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}\\
&\quad + \frac{2\kappa_0 (n\overline{x}_{1:n}-n\mu_0)(m\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} - m\mu_0)}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}\\
&= \beta_n + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{n+m} (x_i - \overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)})^2 + R_{n,m}\end{align}
with
\begin{align}
R_{n,m}&=\frac{1}{2}n(\overline{x}_{1:n}-\overline{x}_{1:n+m})^2+ \frac{1}{2}m(\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}- \overline{x}_{1:n+m})^2\\
&\quad + \frac{\kappa_0 n^2(\overline{x}_{1:n} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}+ \frac{\kappa_0 m^2(\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}\\
&\quad + \frac{2\kappa_0 nm(\overline{x}_{1:n}-\mu_0)(\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} - \mu_0)}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}- \frac{\kappa_0 n(\overline{x}_{1:n} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n)}\\
&=\frac{nm}{2(n+m)}(\overline{x}_{1:n}-\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)})^2\\
&\quad + \frac{\kappa_0 n^2(\overline{x}_{1:n} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}+ \frac{\kappa_0 m^2(\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}\\
&\quad + \frac{2\kappa_0 nm(\overline{x}_{1:n}-\mu_0)(\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} - \mu_0)}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)} - \frac{\kappa_0 n(\overline{x}_{1:n} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n)}\\
&= \overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}^2 \left\{ \frac{nm}{2(n+m)} + \frac{\kappa_0 m^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}\right\}\\
&\quad + \overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} \left\{ - \frac{2nm}{2(n+m)}\overline{x}_{1:n} - \frac{2\kappa_0 m^2\mu_0}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\left. + \frac{2\kappa_0 nm(\overline{x}_{1:n}-\mu_0)}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}
\right\}\\
&\quad+ \frac{nm}{2(n+m)}\overline{x}_{1:n}^2+ \frac{\kappa_0 n^2(\overline{x}_{1:n} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)} - \frac{2\kappa_0 nm(\overline{x}_{1:n}-\mu_0)\mu_0}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}- \frac{\kappa_0 n(\overline{x}_{1:n} - \mu_0)^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n)}+ \frac{\kappa_0 m^2\mu_0^2}{2(\kappa_0 + n+m)(n+m)}\\
&=\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}^2 \frac{\kappa_nm}{2(\kappa_n +m)}\\
&\quad +\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}\overbrace{\frac{2m}{2(\kappa_n +m)(n+m)}
\left\{ -[\kappa_n+m-\kappa_0]n \overline{x}_{1:n}-[n+m]\kappa_0\mu_0\right\}}^{-2\frac{\kappa_nm}{2(\kappa_n+m)}\mu_n}\\
&\quad +\frac{n\overline{x}_{1:n}^2}{2(\kappa_n+m)\kappa_n(n+m)}
 \overbrace{\left\{(\kappa_n+m)\kappa_nm+\kappa_0\kappa_nn-\kappa_0(\kappa_n+m)(n+m)\right\}}^{mn^2+nm^2=mn(m+n)}\\
&\quad -2\frac{n\overline{x}_{1:n}\kappa_0\mu_0}{2(\kappa_n+m)\kappa_n(n+m)}\overbrace{\left\{ n\kappa_n+m\kappa_n-(\kappa_n+m)(n+m)\right\}}^{-(n+m)m}\\
&\quad +\frac{\kappa_0\mu_0^2}{2(\kappa_n+m)\kappa_n(n+m)}\overbrace{\left\{ n^2\kappa_n+2nm\kappa_n+m^2\kappa_n-n(\kappa_n+m)(n+m)\right\}}^{\kappa_0m(n+m)}\\
&=\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}^2 \frac{\kappa_nm}{2(\kappa_n +m)}
-2\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)}\mu_n \frac{\kappa_nm}{2(\kappa_n +m)}+ \mu_n^2 \frac{\kappa_nm}{2(\kappa_n +m)}\\
&= \frac{\kappa_n m }{2(\kappa_n + m)} \, (\overline{x}_{(n+1):(n+m)} - \mu_n)^2
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your patience in answering! I saw you edit the answer so many times, and I have checked the final version, it is correct! Thank you exactly!